# Cannot directly reject traffic on port 25

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, ubuntu-10.04, ufw

My server is running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and I want to reject traffic to port 25. The goal is this:

```
$ telnet {ip} 25
Trying {ip}...
telnet: connect to address {ip}: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I've tried using `iptables` directly, but that failed. Instead, I'm now trying `uwf`:

```
$ ufw reject 25
```

However, it doesn't work as expected:

```
$ telnet {ip} 25
Trying {ip}...
# Waiting for a minute…
telnet: connect to address {ip}: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

If I try the same with any other port (say, 23), it works without the waiting time. This is strange, because nothing is going on on port 25 according to `netstat`.

**How can I reject traffic to port 25 directly, without this delay?**

Note that the same technique on another server worked.

**Update:** here's the relevant part of `iptables`:

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:www 
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp reject-with tcp-reset 
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:25 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:telnet reject-with tcp-reset 
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:23 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

**Update: answers to comments**

- `ufw deny 25` does not work either.
- I'm connecting from a remote location.

Comment: Can you use deny instead of reject and check if it helps?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the server from within the same LAN or from a remote location?

Comment: I've added clarifications to the question.

Answer (score 0):

[**tcpdump**](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) time:

```
tcpdump -s0 -w /tmp/tracefile.pcap tcp port 25
```

CTRL-C when done testing, then load the file up in Wireshark.

Comment: Done that, but strangely enough I get "0 packets received by filter", "0 packets dropped by kernel". Could that mean some other firewall is intercepting traffic to port 25? (Doing the same with the blocked port 23 results in 2 received packets.)

Comment: The traffic never reaches your server.